# Best way to handle multi threaded applications from running code concurrently

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, service

I have an automatic betting BOT.

I use a Windows Service and timers to set off a job every 30 seconds in its own thread that takes bets from the DB, loops through and places them.

However in certain occurrences when the job is too long (over 30 seconds) I can get the same bet being placed twice using the same BetPK (unique ID) as the job for placing it runs at the same time as a previously started thread.

I am using C#, NET 4, VS 2012.

At the moment I set a "locked" flag in a table when the job to place bets runs and then unset it on finishing. So if another job runs and the job is locked it will return ASAP. However this is relying on the DB and network traffic.

What would be the best way in C# to prevent a job started by a timer thread from clashing with a previously started thread. I am thinking I could set a flag IN the service controller that spawns the threads so if a job is running another one won't spawn.

However I would like to learn the correct way to handle multi threaed clashes like this. I just lost a couple of hundred pounds today due to 2 LAY bets being placed at exactly the same time. As only one record existed for the Bet, the last bet placed had the Betfair ID updated so I had no clue about the duplicate until I checked Betfairs own page.

I do already do checks to see if the bet has already been placed before trying to place it but in cases where the "placebet" method is running on the same Bet record at exactly the same time then this is no good.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with relying on the DB and network for locks?  The best way to lock a record is to lock a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the best solution is to keep the locks in the database. The app should be as stateless as possible. You already have a great solution.

Locking inside of your app is error prone and the errors are catastrophic (deadlock, the app stops to work until manually restarted). Locking using the database is much easier, and errors are recoverable.

Just get the locking with the database right. Ask a new question where you post details on what you're doing. I recommend that you `XLOCK` any betting jobs that you're working on. That way they can only be executed once. Use the power of database locks and transactions to make this work. This is *by far* easier than app-level threading.

Comment: Okay, so your saying the implementation I put in today of having a lock when new pending bets are being placed, and then unlocked afterwards so that any other thread running that tries to place bets at the same time is met with an empty recordset (due to the lock flag being set in the DB) is the best solution? I thought maybe the use of the DB and Network traffic would have slowed this down but this is how I have handled previous threading issues so if it works thats the best way you're saying?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. You have to acknowledge that you're going to make mistakes, have bugs, introduce races and deadlocks. This is the way our job works. The database covers your ass in those cases by automatically resolving deadlocks and giving you strong data consistency guarantees. I suggest you do a little research how this is usually done (https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql+server+queue+table). This concept of adding and dequeueing jobs is called a queue table. (Don't be mislead to use service broker...).

Answer (score 0):

You could always try implementing a db like Redis (redis.io) that offers built in POP functions (http://redis.io/commands/lpop). Redis has a C# client and is super useful for any kind of app where speed is crucial as it keeps the entire db in memory. It's also single threaded which makes it easy to implement distributors for multi-consumer type applications.

I'd also recommend checking out http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis as it lays out the pros and cons for Redis and other dbs. Might help you make future db decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I wanted to throw this out there for anybody that stumbles across it.

C# (and presumably VB.NET) offers a couple of nice options for handling thread synchronization. You can use the `lock` keyword to block execution until a given lock is available, or `Monitor.TryEnter()` if you want to specify a timeout (possibly immediately) for taking the lock.

For either of these approaches, you need an object to use for locking. Pretty much any object will do; if you aren't synchronizing access to some object itself (collection, database connection, whatever), you can even just instantiate a throwaway `object`. For a polling timer, the latter is typical.

First, make sure you have an object to use for synchronization:

```
public class DatabasePollingClass {
    object PollingTimerLock = new object();
    ...
```

Now, if you want the polling threads to block indefinitely waiting for their turn, use the `lock` keyword:

```
public class DatabasePollingClass {
    object PollingTimerLock = new object();
    ...

    protected void PollingTimerCallback() {
        lock (PollingTimerLock) {
            //Useful stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Only a single thread will be allowed within the `lock (PollingTimerLock)` block of code at a time. All other threads will wait indefinitely, then resume executing as soon as they can acquire the lock for themselves.

However, you probably don't want that behavior. If you'd rather have the subsequent threads abort immediately (or after a short wait) if another polling thread is still running, you can use `Monitor.TryEnter()` when taking the lock. This does require slightly more caution, however:

```
public class DatabasePollingClass {
    object PollingTimerLock = new object();
    ...

    protected void PollingTimerCallback() {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(PollingTimerLock)) { //Acquires lock on PollingTimerLock object
            try {
                //Useful stuff here
            } finally {
                //Releases lock.
                //You MUST do this in a finally block! (See below.)
                Monitor.Exit(PollingTimerLock);
            }
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Warning: Polling timer overlap. Skipping.");
        }
    }
}
```

The additional caution stems from the fact that, unlike the `lock` keyword, `Monitor.TryEnter()` requires you to manually release the lock when you're finished with it. In order to guarantee that this happens, you need to wrap your whole critical section in a `try` block, and release the lock in the `finally` block. This is to ensure that the lock will be released, even if the polling method fails or returns early. If the method returned without releasing the lock, your program would effectively be hung, as no further threads would be able to acquire the lock.

Another option, which doesn't use locking mechanisms, would be to configure your Timer without a repeat period, i.e. a one-shot Timer. At the end of your polling method, you would dispose the old Timer, and set a new one (you would also need to do this within a `finally` block to guarantee that the Timer gets reset by the end of the method). This approach would be useful if you want to poll the database at a certain interval since the *end* of the previous polling. It's a subtle distinction, but it also solves the problem of concurrent polling attempts.

Note that this is a *really* simple thread concurrency example. As long as all of your locking is happening on threads separate from your UI thread (the message pump itself can become a point of contention), and you're only ever locking a single object, you shouldn't have to worry too much about deadlocks. Those can be really unpleasant to debug; the symptom is usually "application stops responding, and now you get to guess which threads are waiting on what".